# How to perform OCR on PDF/Image documents in SharePoint Online document library?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ocr

I am new in SharePoint online (office 365). I want to perform OCR on PDF/Image documents which are stored in document library.
I am doing the OCR on onprems SharePoint 2010 foundation server using farm solution.
Steps:

- Get the document.
- Read the document
- If unable to read then perform OCR and get the text inside.
- Update the document metadata property with the extracted property.

Please help. Please ask if not cleared.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u know about http://www.darkblueduck.com/ ??

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat: Thanks. Its really good question. I don't know and I have to analyze it but not now because I am busy some other project. Thanks again.